# batch script was unexpected this time

Tags: batch-file, scripting

after running this script shows somesoftware was unexpected this time i am using windows 7 64 bit. trying to get installed location of software using registry. if i echo THE_NAME then i get proper installed location but script exits in if else says  somesoftware was unexpected this time

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\somesoftware
set VALUE_NAME=InstallDirectory

SET THEME_NAME=
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=2,*" %%a in (`REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\somesoftware" /v InstallDirectory`) DO (
    SET THEME_NAME=%%b
)
echo %THEME_NAME%
if defined THEME_NAME (
set PathValue= %THEME_NAME%

     ) else (
   echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not make use of KEY_NAME or VALUE_NAME, and this might be just how you trimmed your example down.

I modified your script as shown below for testing, and it appeared to work as I expected.

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\%1
set VALUE_NAME=InstallDirectory

SET THEME_NAME=
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=2,*" %%a in (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v %VALUE_NAME%`) DO (
    SET THEME_NAME=%%b)
echo THEME_NAME=%THEME_NAME%
if NOT ""=="%THEME_NAME%" (
    set PathValue=%THEME_NAME%
    echo PathValue=%PathValue% 
) else (
    echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
```

NOTE: I changed the IF test to just test for empty string, an echo for my own debugging, I used %1 so I could test...

You will want to use this as a guide to inform your final script.

Comment: if you set a variable to nothing (empty), it gets **un**defined - which your testcase clearly shows.

Comment: @Stephan, Good catch...i thought i double checked that.  I have removed the bogus example from my answer.